# css selectors for 5 col footer menu in joomla?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to line up a footer menu and to select only the first list elements as single selection

```
<ul class="someclass">
    <li><!--this is what I am trying to capture-->

        <a>something arbitrary here</a>
        <ul>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>something arbitrary here</a>
        <ul>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>something arbitrary here</a>
        <ul>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
            <li>list elemnts here</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to select **all** the top `<li>` elements, without directly selecting every other interior `<li>` elements. which css selectors should I use?

Comment: `ul.someclass:first-child{...}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.someclass > li:first-child {
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yUMwD/

Or to select all `li`s on that level:

```
.someclass > li {
}
```

`>` means 'child element', so it's would take the `li` that is directly under `.comeclass`

Comment: thanks you for the quick response, but it's only selecting the first group of lists, and What I intended was to select all the 3 groups separately

Comment: You're welcome! You should consider marking my answer as 'Accepted' if it really helped solving your problem.

Comment: I have another question, which selector should I use if I am aiming to select only the first `<a>` tags within the lists? (consider that there are `<a>` tags nested within every other list item...)

Comment: You should put another question for that, with proper HTML example.

Comment: ok, did so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175121/css-selector-pre-nesting-list-item