# css selector pre-nesting list item

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
    <ul class="someclass">
        <li>
            <a>something arbitrary here</a><!--this is what I am trying to capture-->
            <ul>
                <li><a>list elemnts here</a></li>
                <li><a>list elemnts here</a></li>
                <li><a>list elemnts here</a></li>
                <li><a>list elemnts here</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a>something arbitrary here</a><!--this is what I am trying to capture-->
           <ul>
                <li><a>list elemnts here</a></li>
                <li><a>list elemnts here</a></li>
                <li><a>list elemnts here</a></li>
                <li><a>list elemnts here</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
  </ul>
```

I am trying to use CSS to "extract" the first list items that are marked. which css selectors should I use? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `>` to select direct child elements: http://jsfiddle.net/v25s5/

```
.someclass > li > a {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to learn more about CSS selectors:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

"8. X > Y

```
div#container > ul {

border: 1px solid black;

}
```

The difference between the standard X Y and X > Y is that the latter will only select direct children. For example, consider the following markup.

```
<div id="container">
   <ul>
      <li> List Item
        <ul>
           <li> Child </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> List Item </li>
      <li> List Item </li>
      <li> List Item </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

A selector of #container > ul will only target the uls which are direct children of the div with an id of container. It will not target, for instance, the ul that is a child of the first li.

For this reason, there are performance benefits in using the child combinator. In fact, it's recommended particularly when working with JavaScript-based CSS selector engines."